# Elixir : Writing Parameterized Function using & Notation

Tags: elixir

**Is it possible to write parameterized function using & notation?**

Here is an example of parameterized function from *Programming Elixir* book of *Dave Thomas*

```
title = fn (title) -> ( fn (name) -> title <> " "  <> name end ) end

mrs = title.("Mrs.")
IO.puts mrs.("Rose")
```

Output of above program is:

```
Mrs. Rose
[Finished in 0.6s]
```

Can `title` be written using & notation?  Example of & notation is given below

```
iex> square = &(&1 * &1)
#Function<6.17052888 in :erl_eval.expr/5>

iex> square.(8)
64
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Gazler correctly suggested this is not possible due to syntax limitations, but you can achieve a similar result with partial application. The difference here is that the `title` function will return a result directly, instead of returning a function. The `mrs` function can then do a partial application by "prefilling" the first argument.

```
title = &(&1 <> " "  <> &2)
mrs = &title.("Mrs.", &1)
IO.puts mrs.("Rose")
```

Answer (score 6):

This will not be possible. Attempting to use the capture(`&`) function syntax in a function declared with the capture syntax will raise a `CompileError`

```
iex(1)> &(&(&1))      
** (CompileError) iex:2: nested captures via & are not allowed: &&1
    (elixir) src/elixir_fn.erl:108: :elixir_fn.do_capture/4
    (elixir) src/elixir_exp.erl:229: :elixir_exp.expand/2
    (elixir) src/elixir_exp.erl:10: :elixir_exp.expand/2
```